# How to solve this equation $~f(f(x))=f(x)~$?

Tags: calculus, functions

> If $~f(x)~$ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$, and $~f(f(x))=f(x)~$, then prove that $f(x)=x$ or $Constant$.
>
> Moreover, if the function is only continuous, does the conclusion still hold?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: What have you tried? That $f$ is assumed differentiable suggests that you should derive the equation. What can you conclude if $f'(x)\not=0$?

Comment: Hint. Let $I = f(\mathbb{R})$ and observe that $I$ is a (possibly degenerate) interval on which $f(x) = x$. Now if $f$ is non-constant so that $I$ is non-degenerate, show that $I = \mathbb{R}$ using differentiability of $f$. If only continuity is assumed, then we have counter-examples such as $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x > 1 \\ x, & -1 \leq x \leq 1, \\ -1, & x < -1 \end{cases} $$

Comment: @ThomasRot I just get $f’(f(x))=1$ when $f’(x)\ne 0$,and I don’t know how to use it to illustrate that $f(x)=x$ on the whole real number field. Would you please give directions? Thanks!

Comment: @SangchulLee Sorry, I don’t know how to prove $I$ is equal to $\mathbb{R} by the differentiability of $f(x)$. Would you elaborate? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I = f(\mathbb{R})$ denote the range of $f$. Assume that $f$ is non-constant without losing the generality. Since $f$ is continuous, this implies that $I$ is an interval of non-zero length. Also, the functional equation tells that $f(x) = x$ on $I$.

**Step 1.** $I$ is a closed interval. Indeed, if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $I$ that converges to some $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then

$$ x = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = f(x) $$

and so, $x \in f(\mathbb{R}) = I$.

**Step 2.** We will prove the following claim.

> **Claim.** Let $a \in I$. Then we claim that we can find $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \subseteq I$.

Before proving this, notice that this proves $I = \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, if $I$ is not all of $\mathbb{R}$, then there are 3 possibilities, $I = [a, b]$ for some $a < b$, or $I = (-\infty, b]$ for some $b$, or $I = [a, \infty)$ for some $a$. Now for all these 3 types of intervals, the above claim must fail, a contradiction.

(*Remark.* In case OP is acquainted with the basic point-set topology, here is the motivation of the claim: The above claim essentially tells that $I$ is open. This is important, since the only non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is both open and closed is $\mathbb{R}$.)

Let us return to the proof of the claim. Let $a \in I$. Since $f$ is differentiable and $f(x) = x$ on $I$, we know that $f'(x) = 1$ on $I$. From this, we can find $p < a < q$ such that $f(p) < f(a) < f(q)$. This is intuitively clear because $f$ is in 'increasing-state at $a$'. A more rigorous proof can be made by appealing to the proof by contradiction. For example, assume that $f(x) \geq f(a)$ for all $x < a$. Then

$$ 1 = f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a^-} \underbrace{\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}}_{\leq 0} \leq 0, $$

a contradiction. So $f(p) < f(a)$ for some $p < a$, and the other half follows by the same reasoning. This tells that $a = f(a) \in [f(p), f(q)] \subseteq I$ by the intermediate-value theorem, and so, the claim follows by choosing $\epsilon > 0$ small so that $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \subseteq [f(p), f(q)]$. ////